# App IOS crash on UITextView field in IBOutlet xib on XCODE 6

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I have a problem on UITextView field in file xib because before that load view the app crash.So I have gone in file.h and I have seen that @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *description linked to file xib has the warnings

[image]

I have tried that if I delete the IBOutlet UITextView *description and the object from file xib, I have discovered that the problem is generated from it.

How to resolve this problem?
Thanks

The message from error compiler is below:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key description.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSObject got the description method, so you should use another variable name in order to avoid issues. Then you should declare your IBOutlets with 'weak' property.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I have changed the name at the variable and now the app works..Thanks